# How to open a specific slider on the next page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup

I want to open a slider on the next page when pressing a button but there is more than one button. Further, when I press one of the buttons then I want the info slider to open the one I clicked on the previous page.

here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("h3.open-close").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(".current")) {
            $(this).removeClass("current");
            $(this).next(".desc").slideUp(400);
        } else {
            $(".desc").slideUp(4.00);
            $("h3.open-close").removeClass("current");

            $(this).addClass("current");
            $(this).next(".desc").slideDown(400);
            $(function () {
                if (window.location.hash) {
                    $(window.location.hash).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: use `.hasClass("current")` instead `is(".current")`!

Comment: Dhaval Marthak. it is not working i want the slider on the next page to open and it is staing closed.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Your updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.hash) {
       $(window.location.hash).show(); // <--if true then do this.
    }
    $("h3.open-close").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(".current")) {
            $(this).removeClass("current");
            $(this).next(".desc").slideUp(400);
        } else {
            $(".desc").slideUp(4.00);
            $("h3.open-close").removeClass("current");

            $(this).addClass("current");
            $(this).next(".desc").slideDown(400);
        }
    });
});
```

You have to check for the hash at dom ready.

Comment: how wil it look like? sorry for the quostions i just started learning jquery.

Comment: it dit not work i do not no why. this is wats before the $(document)             function getAnchor(url)
{
    var index = url.lastIndexOf('#');
    if (index != -1)
        return url.substring(index1);
        
        currentAnchor = getAnchor(location.href);
$("#" + currentAnchor).show();

  $('.desc').slideUp(400);
    $('h4.open-close').removeClass('current');
    $(currentAnchor).addClass('current');
    $(currentAnchor).next('.desc').slideToggle(400);
}

Comment: so your `window.location.hash` returns anything or you have hash in your location bar.

Comment: its better to create a fiddle.

Comment: you mean a different .js file ?

Comment: if you can see when i press diensten, kennis, onderwijs & Opvoeding, Hulpverlening, Onderzoek, Gezondheid it will not open on the next page. you can see it here http://nl.fitrah.nl/diensten/